# Python socket.accept() blocking code before call?

Tags: python, sockets, blocking

I am trying to learn Python sockets and have hit a snare with the socket.accept() method. As I understand the method, once I call accept, the thread will sit and wait for an incoming connection (blocking all following code). However, in the code below, which I got from https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html and am using localhost. I added a print('hello') to the first line of the server. Yet the print doesn't appear until after I disconnect the client. Why is this? Why does accept seem to run before my print yet after I bind the socket?

```
# Echo server program
import socket

print('hello') # This doesn't print until I disconnect the client
HOST = 'localhost'              
PORT = 50007              
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connected by', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
    conn.sendall(data)
conn.close()
```

```
# Echo client program
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'    # The remote host
PORT = 50007              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall('Hello, world')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

Comment: How are you running the server, on the command line, or inside an interactive environment that might try to capture its output? Try adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` (remembering to also `import sys` before that).

Comment: @user4815162342 I am running in the command line. Yet when I used flush it worked! Could you explain in detail? Thanks!

Comment: The standard output is a buffered stream, meaning that when you print something, the output sticks around in an internal buffer until you print enough data to fill it (unlikely in a small program, the buffet is several kilobytes in size), or until the program exits, when all such buffers are automatically flushed. Normally when the output is a terminal, the IO layer automatically switches to *line buffering*, where the buffer is flushed whenever a newline character is printed (which `print` inserts automatically).

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't work on your system, and you have to flush explicitly. Another option is to run `python -u`, which should force unbuffered standard streams.

Comment: Ok! So I was using git bash for windows and that seems to have been the issue. I changed over to my linux terminal and now everything is working as expected! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I've now expanded the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely using an output device on a system that Python's IO doesn't recognize as interactive. As a workaround, you can add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print`.

The standard output is a buffered stream, meaning that when you print something, the output sticks around in an internal buffer until you print enough data to fill the whole buffer (unlikely in a small program, the buffet is several kilobytes in size), or until the program exits, when all such buffers are automatically flushed. Normally when the output is a terminal service, the IO layer automatically switches to line buffering, where the buffer is also flushed whenever a newline character is printed (and which the `print` statement inserts automatically).

For some reason, that doesn't work on your system, and you have to flush explicitly. Another option is to run `python -u`, which should force unbuffered standard streams.